# how to fetch all rows when using array fetch by setdatabuffer()

Tags: oracle, occi

i'am blocked the problem how to fetch all row, that is last left rows when using array fetch by setdatabuffer().
there's 80405 rows in a table named example.
    OcciResultSet resultSet = occi.executeQuery("select x, y from example");

```
const int size = 10000;
double xs[size], ys[size];
ub4 *length = NULL;
resultSet->setDataBuffer(1, &xs[0], oracle::occi::OCCIBDOUBLE, sizeof(xs[0]), length);
resultSet->setDataBuffer(2, &ys[0], oracle::occi::OCCIBDOUBLE, sizeof(ys[0]), length);

int count = 0;
while (resultSet->next(size) == oracle::occi::ResultSet::DATA_AVAILABLE)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("row: %d\n", ++count);
        double x = xs[i];
        double y = ys[i];
    }
}
```

only can fetch the first 80000 rows. last 405 rows are left, how to fetch the last 405 rows.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14294/performance.htm#CHDIDIDE) help? The problem I see in your for loop is that it needs to iterate until i == resultSet->getNumArrayRows(), not `size`. `size` is the maximum number of rows that can be fetched. The actual number of rows fetched might be less and that's why there's a method to tell you how many were actually fetched.

Comment: @jeff6times7, yes, resultSet->getNumArrayRows() is mush safe. but `size` is ok. the description of setdatabuffer() on oracle page `This causes up to numRows amount of data to be fetched for each column. The buffers specified with the setDataBuffer() interface should large enough to hold at least numRows of data`. now only one method: fetch the first 405 rows, then fetch the last 800000 row by array fetch .

Answer (score 0):

On the 8th iteration of the while loop, `size` was 10000 and `getNumArrayRows()` returned an integer between 1 and 10000. There were no more rows and that is why there wasn't a 9th iteration. On the 8th iteration, your for loop printed 0 or more rows from the 7th iteration. The way you're wording your post, you expect the reader to return 80405 rows. But unless you have found a new bug in the ODP, the actual query for the reader returned between 70001 and 80000 rows.

As an example, if the reader's query returned 79999 rows, then your code printed rows 1 through 70000, then rows 70001 through 79999, then row 70000 again. It printed row 70000 again because the reader didn't set the memory for the last elements of the respective arrays and your for loop iterator didn't stop after it processed the last row fetched. In other words, for this example, on the first 7 iterations of the while loop `getNumArrayRows()` returned 10000 and on the 8th iteration it returned 9999.